# How to use whereHas method in Laravel scout,

Tags: laravel, full-text-search

I have been trying to search in both the name column and that's relationship. I have coded as below;
///

```
$posts = ContentForSearch::with("content_type","content_sub_type")->exclude($exclude)->user($user_id_filter)
                    ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
                    ->orWhereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($search) {
                        $q->where('tag', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");
                    })
                    ->orderBy($sort, $order)
                    ->paginate($limit);
```

I have set a searchable Model. I want to change with search method as below;

```
$posts = ContentForSearch::search($search)->orWhere(function ($query) use ($search) {
                    $query->whereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($search) {
                        $q->where('tag', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");
                    });
                })
                ->orderBy($sort, $order)
                ->paginate($limit)->load("content_type","content_sub_type");
```

**Why isnt the code working ? How can i fix it ?**

Model is:

```
class ContentForSearch extends Model{
 use Searchable;

 protected $table = 'content';

 public function searchableAs()
 {
    return 'contents_index';
 }
 public function toSearchableArray()
 {
    $array = $this->toArray();

    // Customize array...

    return ["name"=> null];
 }

 public function content_type()
 {

    return $this->belongsTo(ContentType::class, 'content_type_id');

 }
 public function tags()
 {
    return $this->belongsToMany(ContentTag::class, 'content_content_tags', 'content_id', 'content_tags_id')->withTimestamps();
 }
 // * * *
```

Answer (score 1):

The way fulltext search works with `algolia` and `elastic`, it seems weird that you want to preserve `whereHas()` relationship method. In my opinion it is an either or case, either you want sql relation search or you want full text, if you want full text, i would map all the tags at index building instead. So something like this would work.

```
public function toSearchableArray()
{
    $customArray = $this->toArray();

    $index = 1;
    $this->tags->each(function(Tag $tag) use (&$customArray, &index) {
        $customArray['tag' . $index++] = $tag->tag;
    });

    return $customArray;
}
```

Which will result in an object similar to this being indexed.

```
{
    'name' => 'x',
    'tag1' => 'comment',
    'tag2' => 'post',
}
```

Now searching would provide a similar functionality.

```
ContentForSearch::search($search);
```

Comment: It gives the error; syntax error, unexpected 'index' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: i need a line and your code for that, the code posted seems fine

Comment: Did you get further with this one?

Comment: This should be fairly straight forward to solve, update your question with the code and lets look at it? have similar solution in production as we speak